# VBA - can't properly copy object from Word Document if it isn't active (brought to front)

Tags: vba, ms-word

When I select logo object from footer, `Selection.Copy` creates an object in Clipboard, which - tested in Break Mode - after pasting anywhere appears as 2 next line separators: Chr(13) chr(10) Chr(13) Chr(10).

If after selecting logo object with code, I manually navigate to template document and use CTRL + C, it is properly stored in Clipboard.

I tried `tempDoc.Activate` before `Selection.Copy`, but it doesn't bring template file to front (I have openedDoc open as well at the same time).

```
Sub changeHeadersFooters(openedDoc As Object, tempDoc As Object)

Dim shp As Object, logo As Object
Dim HdFt As Object, hdrOpened As Object    

'create logo object in template doc
For Each HdFt In tempDoc.Sections(1).footers
    If HdFt.Exists Then
        For Each shp In HdFt.Shapes
            If InStr(shp.Name, "image") <> 0 Then Set logo = shp: Exit For
        Next shp
    End If
Next HdFt

Set hdrOpened = openedDoc.Sections(1).footers(1)

logo.Select
Selection.Copy
With hdrOpened.Range
    .Collapse Direction:=1 'wdCollapseStart=1, wdCollapseEnd = 0
    .Paste
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: You can always use `SendKeys` to simulate `CTRL+C`

Comment: I find SendKeys unreliable, but for purpose of narrowing down the issue, I've used `SendKeys "^c", True` instead of Selection.Copy with the same poor effect. If I've properly sent CTRL+C, then the problem lies almost certainly in bringing Word document to front. Can it be done at all? If yes, does Word application need to be visible?